# Outer measure and g_delta set

Tags: outer-measure

[image: Problem and my incomplete solution]

I think that my logic is not wrong, but I can't prove this problem completely. How can I correct my solution if my logic is wrong? If there is nothing wrong, how can I complete proof?

Oh, Korean word [풀이] was not edited... 풀이 means solution.

Comment: Kindly consider typing your question with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead of posting text as a picture.

Comment: I'd like to, but I have not used MathJax... I'll edit if I can after reading formatting tips

Comment: Other than the detail in my A, it is OK.

Answer (score 0):

If $V$ is a family of open intervals let $f(V)= \sum_{I\in V}l(I).$ Then $f(V)\ge m^*(\cup V).$ It may be that $f(V)>m^*(\cup V),$ as the members of $V$ may fail to be disjoint.

Let $W$ be the set of all families of open intervals such that $V\in W\implies \cup V\supset A.$ Then $$m^*(A)=\inf_{V\in W}f(V)\ge \inf_{V\in W}m^*(\cup V).$$

You assume that the "$\ge$" in the line above can be replaced by "$=$". It can be, but you need to prove it, as follows: If $V\in W$ then $\cup V\supset A$ so $m^*(\cup V)\ge m^*(A),$ so $$\inf_{V\in W}m^*(\cup V)\ge m^*(A).$$

Comment: I denote G as open set of which subset is A. so G $\supseteq$A becomes $\cup V$ $\supseteq$A. I think your proof and my proof have no difference. Could you explain more?